# Plot and model longitudinal data with covariates

Tags: r

I have data on 96 countries for 10 years. The data is on the countries' medal tally in Olympic Games for 10 years, the population and gdp in those years.
I want to plot the data so that I can check for the presence of subject specific effects from the plot. How do I go about this?

I tried using:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(medals ~ pop|Year + Countries)
```

and got the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("depth") : 
  no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Also, if I wanted to fit a transition model instead how can I determine the order of AR?

Comment: I see no data argument in that code, and on my machine I get the error message that I was expecting because I have none of those items defined: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Year' not found. If I define a "Year" vector I will just get another error from one of the other undefined symbols. I strongly advise you to use `xyplot` in the manner it was intended, with a dataframe object in which the values for the tokens in your formula are column names and that dataframe is passed to `data=`

Comment: I had used attach(data) command before. I can get the plot if I use only Year or only Countries.

Comment: Friends don't let friends use `attach`. It is the pathway to mysterious errors. The current mystery is what is the name of the dataset with the "real" data and what is its structure. If the name is "data" (in itself a path to confusion) then you should execute: `detach(data)` and supply the "data"-object to the `xyplot` with `data=data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With toy data, what is it that you need from lattice? I can't comment on the transition model question at the end.

```
Countries <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
medals <- 1:4
gdp <- seq(1000000000, 4000000000, 1000000000)
pop <- seq(10000000, 40000000, 10000000)
Year <- c("1970", "1980", "1990", "2000") 
df <- cbind(Countries = country, medals = as.integer(medals), gdp = as.numeric(gdp),
                                                   pop = as.numeric(pop), Year = as.factor(Year))
df.two <- as.data.frame(df)

library(lattice)
xyplot(data = df.two, medals ~ pop|Year + Countries)
```

[image]